# html email rounded button with images

Tags: html, html-email, html-table

I am having trouble making a rounded button with images.. the button displays fine in a browser but inside an email client (this includes yahoo and gmail) the button breaks..
here is the HTML table code that i am using:

```
<table width="144" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="background-color: #9C084A">
  <tr>
    <td width="12"><img src="http://thehotdeal.net/clients/1/padma/1.gif" width="12" height="12" border="0" alt="...">
    </td>
    <td width="130"></td>
    <td width="12">
      <img src="http://thehotdeal.net/clients/1/padma/2.gif" width="12" height="12" border="0" alt="...">
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"></td>
   <td align="center">
     <p style="padding: 0"> <span mc:edit="date" style="color: #ffffff;">2012 - $25</span></p>
   </td>
   <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>
   <img src="http://thehotdeal.net/clients/1/padma/3.gif" width="12" height="12" border="0" alt="...">
 </td>
 <td cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0"></td>
 <td>
   <img src="http://thehotdeal.net/clients/1/padma/4.gif" width="12" height="12" border="0" alt="...">
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

[Here is how this looks.. notice a line below it..!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oTHA.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few elements could be altered to make this render better cross client:

- `display:block;` on your images
- put your background color on each `td` individually using `bgcolor="#9C084A"`
- explicitly set width and height on each `td`
- use `valign` on your images if need be

Here is the jsfiddle with these alterations - http://jsfiddle.net/X5QTR/

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what i needed. Thank you for the useful information.